# How to use COLLATE in MySQL prepared statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement, collate

I need to specify COLLATE in connection with LIKE inside a prepared statement inside a stored procedure, e.g. `<col> LIKE ? COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci`. I'm getting the following error:

```
COLLATION 'utf8_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary'
```

I have also tried to cast the parameter by all of: `LIKE _utf8 ? COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci`, `LIKE CONVERT(? AS utf8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` and `LIKE CAST(? AS varchar CHARACTER SET utf8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` but the error is then something like:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar CHARACTER SET utf8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ...
```

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I encountered this problem while using PHP `PDO`. Finally I got the following solution: 

`$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the `_utf8` is part of the syntax for [string literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html). Since you don't have, you cannot use it.

The [signature for `CAST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) is this:

> `CAST(expr AS type)`

I think [you really want `CONVERT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert):

> `CONVERT(expr,type), CONVERT(expr USING transcoding_name)`
>
> [...]
>
> CONVERT() with USING converts data between different character sets.
>   In MySQL, transcoding names are the same as the corresponding
>   character set names. For example, this statement converts the string
>   'abc' in the default character set to the corresponding string in the
>   utf8 character set:
>
> ```
> SELECT CONVERT('abc' USING utf8);
> ```

Comment: Thank you. My mistake. As written incorrectly in the question, my syntax `CONVERT(...AS...)` was incorrect. Correct is `CONVERT(...USING...)`. Now it works.